# LinkedIn send a message

Tags: c#, .net, linkedin-api, sendmessage

I want to send a message to LinkedIn user from my connections. I try the following code:

```
            string s = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<mailbox-item>
  <recipients>
    <recipient>
      <person path='/people/1234567' />
    </recipient>
  </recipients>
  <subject>Congratulations on Test.</subject>
  <body>Test Here</body>
</mailbox-item>";

            string url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox?oauth2_access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX";

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            webRequest.Timeout = 10000;
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write(s);
            }

            WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

I get an exception "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." on the last string. What is incorrectly?

Comment: Does this work with Fiddler (or something like it)?  If so, check the encoding.

Comment: I see a header content-type="text/xml" and TextView="my_xml". What is incorrectly?